# Firefox connect localhost via proxy server

Tags: firefox, networking, proxy

In my computer I have proxy server and web server. Both of them are running and my Firefox is configured to this proxy server. Every connection is working perfectly however, I need to connect my local web server which is localhost. And in Firefox proxy settings page "No proxy for" field if I remove localhost from there, I am getting "ProtocolException" and cannot even connect to my localhost. How can I connect to localhost through proxy server ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, I think you are connecting via a local proxy and are trying to request a web page from a local web server. Is this correct?

Local host is usually on 127.0.0.1 so you will need to tell Firefox to look at http://127.0.0.1:[webserver port number]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Yes exactly both of them are local but I need that all traffic should go through local proxy to local web server, now it's going directly to web server because in Firefox proxy settings : "No proxy for" -> "localhost, 127.0.0.1";

Comment: What port is your webserver running on?